# register for push notifications not working for some Device

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

Hi i am facing strange issue Regarding Push notifications that not Appear popup/alert telling me to accept push notifications isn't displayed for some device and some device its working fine. I am not understand where is mistake in my code. i am also trying re-generate my Provisioning Profile after I enabled Push Notifications for the certificate. can any one please guide me how to solve this issue.

**HERE IS MY CODE FOR PUSH NOTIFICATION:-**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
    {
        NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
    }

    - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
    }

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        // Let the device know we want to receive push notifications
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
            (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

        return YES;
    }
```

I am using above code for some device all working fine. but some are not reserving at-list registration popup/alert. whats probability for this type of issue?
please Help me.

Comment: Its due to your internet connection , so just check your internet connection.

:)

Comment: sir its checking very well.

Comment: Are all devices added to your certificates?

Comment: please refer link below   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758496/push-notifications-arent-send-to-some-devices

Comment: @dhaya this is not useful bcz i m not sending pushnotification in bulk in a day pushNotification sent 2 time only. in issue is that this is not asking for register :(

Comment: I didnt understand what you get down vote, I am facing exactly same issue at the moment

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check your bundle identifier, re-create your certificates and re-install it> Then make a new IAP and try again. May be it will help out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your jail broken devices. Because Jailbroken and hacktivated iOS devices never generate the token. Hence, push notifications cannot work. Please check this [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/57226) also. I think this is the reason by which you faced this problem.

Comment: may be i pass this link to my client and let you knw after checking this. thank you for answering

Comment: Nope :( its not a jailbreak device client use anyway thanks for help Ajay

Answer (score -1):

Nitin, I think this problem is related to your device version means you have implemented your code on xcode 4.x version and may be you are checking Push Notification on device which is having lower version which is not compatible with your xcode.

Good Luck.

Comment: thank's for answer varsha you mean that ios4,5,6..? but as par my thinking there is not any changes for push-notification register method with device iOS version. please if you have any link or other related contain of this issue please provide it with your answer

Comment: Nitin, There is inconsistency between higher version devices and lower one's.I have also faced this problem for some other cases. Now, Please try to install your app on the higher version devices and check is it working or not?