# Not able to register for push notification for few ipad devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

We have distribution provisioning profile having `push notification` enabled. For most of the ipad devices we are able to register for `push notification` and getting the device token, but for very few device we are unable to register for push notfication, and we are unable to retrieve the device token, at the same time none of the below `delegate` methods are getting invoked for push notification:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken;

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

Any help on this would be  apprieciated.

Thanks
shahnawaz

Comment: What do you mean by unable to register for push notifications on some devices? What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow these two steps:

1. Check your bundle identifier, re-create your certificates and re-install it. Then make a new IAP and try again. May be it will help out.
2. May be the problem is your jail broken devices. Because Jailbroken and hacked iOS devices never generate the token. Hence, push notifications cannot work. Please check these [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/57226) & [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11766840/1450762) also. I think this is the reason by which you faced this problem.

Good Luck !!

Answer (score 0):

Did you receive an apple APNS alert message while installing the app in your iPads? If not you are sure missing something while creating cert and profile.

To resolve this:

1. delete your certificates and provisioning profile.
2. Create the certificate and provisioning profile again and install.

Apple push notification also wont work, if your email id provided while requesting for CAR is not a member in that apple account.